# Apache2: Mod_rewrite wildcard text.html

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

We have changed e-commerce vendors and I need to perserve some of the SEO we've done.
I want to do a 301 for a set of pages to a single new URL

I have a set of pages that end all with the same tickets.htm.  So, for example, I have a pages like /blank_tickets.htm and /concert_tickets.htm and the list goes on.

So I tried this:
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)tickets.htm$ /t/tickets/types/standard

I tried variations of this no leading / no $, etc.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but my Google-fu is not returning a relevant example.

Thanks!

Comment: Your RewriteRule doesn't seem to make 301, but to serve the other URL, the ticket.htm URL as well.
Also, what is your problem? Is your expression never matched?

Comment: yeah I'm still getting 404 for the removed pages rather than being redirected to the  /t/tickets/types/standard URL

Comment: What happens if you add `[R,L]` to the end of the directive? (With some whitespace before it, of course.)

Comment: Yes, the R flag is used to create a browser redirection, but L only means that no further RewriteRule is applied, so that cannot be the issue. Same with R, because than he wouldn't get a 404 error, but the correct page loaded without a HTTP redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't escape the dot. Use \. in your regular expression at the .htm part.

Edit: also use the [R=301] flag, or simply [R] to produce a HTTP 301 header.

Comment: changed to:RewriteRule ^(.*)tickets\.htm$ /t/tickets/types/standard [R] same result

Comment: Does `/t/tickets/types/standard` exist? Is it a subject to a next RewriteRule? If it is, then your order of the rewrites may cause the problem, if you're using the [L] flag on a preceding rule.
And sorry, I just realized that the dot couldn't be the problem, since it matches all.

Comment: One more thing. I tested these exact rules, and they're working on my Apache. But: did you also put `RewriteEngine on` at the beginning of all? Because if you miss it, no rewrite will work.

Comment: it's my only rewrite rule and I have RewriteEngine on at the top of my config file... does it need to be in the VirtualHost section? and yes the destination exists

Comment: I'm confused a bit then, because you seem to do everything right. RewriteRules can be per directory configured, they don't necessarily belong to the VirtualHost section.
Try tinkering with the RewriteBase directive. I guess the only thing that you .htaccess misses is `RewriteBase /`, but instead of `/` can something else depending on your URL structure.